# Hexadecimal to Image Conversion

Tags: python, image, opencv, hex, byte

I am converting the hexadecimal files to images. The input files are converted to byte string using `binascii` library. The problem arises when the byte string is written to form an image. The output of all the hexadecimal files is same. I will be grateful if someone provides me a solution.

Here is my code:

```
import binascii
import cv2
import os
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

#Hide the root window that comes by default
root=Tk()
root.withdraw()

#Browse and select txt files
dir=[]
dir=filedialog.askopenfilenames(
        initialdir="C:\Binaries\Hexadecimal_Text_Files", 
        title="Open Text file", 
        filetypes=(("Text Files", "*.txt"),)
        )

#Reading data in txt files and decoding hexadecimal characters
for x in dir:
        tf=open(x)#Open file    
        data=tf.read()#Read data in file
        data=data.replace(' ','')#Remove whitespaces
        data=data.replace('\n','')#Remove breaks in lines
        data=binascii.a2b_hex(data)
        tf.close()

#Extract txt filename without extension
        pathname, extension = os.path.splitext(f"{x}")#Split path into filename and extenion
        filename = pathname.split('/')#Get filename without txt extension
        filepath=f"C:\Binaries\Images\{filename[-1]}.png"#Defining name of image file same as txt file

#Write data into image
        with open(filepath, 'wb') as image_file:
                img=image_file.write(data)
    
#Resizing Image
        img=cv2.resize(img,(500,500))
        cv2.imwrite(filepath,img)
```

Output:

[image: enter link description here]

Comment: Hexadecimal Files Google Drive Link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wEL0VuCTZ-Ttw94XB-bVoOSju_tIPp9Z/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have converted the hexadecimal files into images by using numpy array and Pillow. Now I am getting different images.

```
import numpy as np
import binascii
import os
from PIL import Image as im
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

# Hide the root window that comes by default
root = Tk()
root.withdraw()

# Browse and select txt files
dir = []
dir = filedialog.askopenfilenames(
initialdir="C:\Binaries\Folder_3",
title="Open Text file",
filetypes=(("Text Files", "*.txt"),)
)

# Reading data in txt files and decoding hexadecimal characters
for temp in dir:
    tf = open(temp)  # Open file
    data = tf.read()  # Read data in file
    data= data.replace('\'','')   #Remove label
    data = data.replace(' ', '')  # Remove whitespaces
    data = data.replace('\n', '') # Remove breaks in lines
    data = binascii.a2b_hex(data)
    tf.close()
           
#Converting bytes array to numpy array
    a = np.frombuffer(data, dtype='uint8')
    #print(a) //Display array

#Finding optimal factor pair for size of image    
    x = len(a)
    val1=0
    val2=0
    for i in range(1, int(pow(x, 1 / 2))+1):
        if x % i == 0:
                val1=i
                val2=int(x / i)

#Converting 1-D to 2-D numpy array                
    a = np.reshape(a, (val1, val2))
    #print(a) #Display 2-D array

#Writing array to image
    data = im.fromarray(a)

# Split path into filename and extenion
    pathname, extension = os.path.splitext(f"{temp}")
    filename = pathname.split('/')  # Get filename without txt extension

# Defining name of image file same as txt file
    filepath = f"C:\Binaries\Images_3\{filename[-1]}.png"

#Resize image    
    data=data.resize((500,500))
    
#Saving image into path    
    data.save(filepath)
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I made my own version because I could not get yours to work, but if you want to make yours work, at least one problem with I found is with this line:

```
img=cv2.resize(img,(500,500))
```

by printing all the variables after the supposed "conversion", I found that your variable `img` in the previous line is not an image but the result of `image_file.write(data)` which returns the number of bytes written to the file and not the image itself, which is probably why it always prints the same image.

Here is my version

```
root=Tk()
root.withdraw()

file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(
    initialdir = "C:\Binaries\Images", 
    title = "Select Hexadecimal Text File", 
    filetypes = (("Text Files", "*.txt"),)
)

with open(file_path, "r") as hex_file:
    hex_data = hex_file.read().replace("\n", "")
    #replaces white spaces and new lines from file
    binary_data = binascii.a2b_hex(hex_data)
    #converts the hexadecimal data to binary

pathname, extension = os.path.splitext(file_path)
image_path = pathname + ".png"
#image path and format 

with open(image_path, "wb") as image_file:
    image_file.write(binary_data)
    #writing the binary data to image file

img = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

#if txt file is empty
if img is None:
    print("Error: Image not loaded!")
else:
    cv2.imshow("image", img)
    #waits for key input and closes when pressing any key
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Your code is not not loading the images. The aim of my code is to create different images from hexadecimal files of Zone Alarm (.zap) format. I hope you visited the Google Drive link of hexadecimal files that I shared in the comment. You identified that resize was issue in my code. I wanted to bring into your knowledge that if I remove resize the images get corrupted.

Comment: @SalaarImran Hello! Oh, I thought you were trying to just convert `.txt` files with hexadecimal values formatted with no spacing into `.png` files, which this code does, my apologies. Could you give a new link for me to test out, current google drive link says I cant access it.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/d1sljor64nan2g6/Hexadecimal_Text_Files.zip?dl=0

Comment: Those are not `.zap` files but exe files converted to text, that is hexadecimal representation of binary data and it can't be turned into an image unless it is a png.txt file...